# Converting String to DateTime BetweenTwo Classes

Tags: c#

For a project I am doing, I have to have the all the details of a person in a separate Person class, which includes a DateTime for their DOB.
The code from the Person class is:

```
public Customer(string firstName, string lastName, string address, string 
dateOfBirth, string contactNumber, string email)
    {
        _FirstName = firstName;
        _LastName = lastName;
        _Address = address;
        _DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        _ContactNumber = contactNumber;
        _Email = email;
    }

private string _DateOfBirth;
    public string DateOfBirth
    {
        get { return _DateOfBirth; }
        set { _DateOfBirth = value.ToDateTime(); }
    }
public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Name: {0} {1}, Address: {2}, DOB: {3}, Contact: {3}, Email: {4}, Total Balance: 6", _LastName, _FirstName, _Address, _DateOfBirth, _ContactNumber, _Email /*Add total balance*/);
    }
```

The input for it within the Program Class would be

```
Customer c1 = new Customer("First name: Arley, ", "Last name: Praise, ", "Address: 12 Hay Rd, ", "Date of birth (DD / MM / YYYY): 02 / 10 / 1990, ", "Mobile: 0412232116, ", "Email: arleyp @gmail.com");
```

Which is why I'm trying to convert the string to DateTime. However, in the Person class, it comes up with the error CS1061 for

```
value.ToDateTime();
```

I tried fixing it and looking at other threads with similar problems but I haven't been able to come up with anything. If there's a better way of doing it, or simply fixing the error, any help will be amazing!

Comment: There's no such method `ToDateTime` on string, like the error message says.

Comment: ... And even if there was such a method, what would you expect it to do? return a `DateTime`? But `_DateOfBirth` is a `string` ...

Comment: perhaps this page will be helpful? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `value` is string and string does not have `ToDateTime` method. That's why you have this error. Read about DateTime.Parse, DateTime.TryParse and Convert.ToDateTime.

Comment: Is there any reason you've made `DateOfBirth` a string property at all? `DateTime` feels like a more natural type for it.

Comment: I'm creating a new person, and since there's various elements within it, we were told to enter it like this:
`Customer c1 = new Customer("First name: Arley, ", "Last name: Praise, ", "Address: 12 Hay Rd, ", "Date of birth (DD / MM / YYYY): 02 / 10 / 1990, ", "Mobile: 0412232116, ", "Email: arleyp @gmail.com");`
This is in within the Program class, and the code that accepts it all is within the Person class (which is separate).

Comment: Right, so I'd convert the string into a `DateTime` in `Program.cs`. In general, I'd recommend using the "natural" data type for a value as far as you can, and only convert to and from strings when you need to, for user interaction. Any other code using `Person` is more likely to find a `DateTime` useful than a string, so that's the more appropriate property. (I realize that for a school assignment there may not be any more code, but it's good to think about this sort of thing early.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no method name "ToDateTime" on string. So you require code to achieve that for your proble.

First, You need to parse the `string` from the retrieved string so that the actual date string can be extracted. Later the extracted `string` need to be converted into `DateTime`. Following code achieves what you require:

```
        var str = "Date of birth (DD / MM / YYYY): 02 / 10 / 1990, ";
        var regex = new Regex(@"\d\d \/ \d\d \/ \d\d\d\d");
        var match = regex.Match(str);

        var date = DateTime.ParseExact(match.ToString().Replace(" ", ""), "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The `date` variable is `DateTime` object. So here you can write the Extension on string type to convert the specified string to DateTime.

```
public static DateTime ToDateTime(this string myString)
    {

        var regex = new Regex(@"\d\d \/ \d\d \/ \d\d\d\d");
        var match = regex.Match(myString);

        var date = DateTime.ParseExact(match.ToString().Replace(" ", ""), "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        return date;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another method.

```
public static string ToDateTime(this myString)
{
    var date = Convert.ToDateTime(myString).ToString("DD / MM / YYYY");
    return date;
}


string YourDateTime = "29-04-2018 09:43:33";

var Result =YourDateTime.ToDateTime();  // "29/04/2018"
```